# "Fudge" vs. "dodge" (an issue, question, etc.), and "fudge" as another term for "cheat" in AE

Tags: verbs, american-english, vocabulary, colloquialisms

In AE, can "fudge" and "dodge" be used just about interchangeably to convey the sense of circumvent [= avoid or try to avoid answering, fulfilling, or performing (duties, questions, issues, etc.)]?

Are these terms acceptable in whatever register of the English language but the most formal prose?

Also, Does "fudge" have any currency in modern day colloquial AE to mean "cheat or welsh [fudge on an exam, fudge on one's promises, etc.]?

Comment: In AmE, 'fudge' in that sense is informal, you probably wouldn't see it in a newspaper often. 'fudge' and 'dodge' are pretty different. 'dodge' means to get out of the way of, as in 'dodgeball'. 'fudge' means to 'slightly modify so as to work'. So it definitely doesn't mean to circumvent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak for AmE, but in BrE, ***fudge*** in OP's context has more the sense of...

> *To reach a makeshift solution by glossing over differences or **blurring distinctions**
>
>    to prevaricate or temporize.*

That definition is from OED, who also flag up...

> ***to fudge and mudge**  [**mudge**: fanciful rhyming alteration of **fudge**]
>
>     first recorded in a speech on 2 October 1980 by British politician David Owen*

Therefore I would say that *fudging* an issue means *distorting/smudging* the issue, so it's not clear exactly what is being discussed. That's somewhat different to *dodging* the issue (actually avoiding addressing it at all, rather than making it confused), and completely different to *cheating*.

Having said that, there are contexts where if a makeshift solution is *fudged/cobbled together*, someone might say you were metaphorically "cheating" because you didn't "follow the rules" which were implicitly expected to be observed by your solution.

Comment: That's pretty much the same in AmE.  "Fudge" definitely has a sense of a short-cut being taken or doing something not entirely on the up-and-up to achieve a goal.  It can also be used to soften the sentiment that someone outright lied about something: ***"He totally fudged his way through that explanation to the boss why our report is not done!"***

Comment: @Kristina: This OP specialises in finding atypical usages where it's not always clear if they're *dialect/idiolect* or plain *error*, but I never heard of *fudge = cheat / welsh* in any BrE context. Are they remotely credible in AmE?

Comment: I'm not having a good day...but I'll venture to say that I have not heard of "fudge" being used to mean "welsh", like welshing on a bet.  I guess that by my understanding of the word, "cheat", I wouldn't use "fudge" there either.  I might say, "I fudged a few of my answers on my test" to mean that I either took a guess at the answer or tried to bamboozle my way through an answer without (hopefully) letting on I didn't know what the heck I was talking about.